# Python numpy.cov results in Memory Error

Tags: python, memory, numpy, covariance

I have a data matrix `dataAsCol` of shape `(n, k)`.

For `k = 93952`, `K = numpy.cov(dataAsCol)` works.

For `k = 94208`, `K = numpy.cov(dataAsCol)` fails and reports `MemoryError` in IPython console.

Is there a limit on the size of matrices that `numpy.cov` accepts?

Here is a snippet of the error shown in IPython console:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1732, in cov
_cache = [outputs]

MemoryError
```

Comment: How large is `n`?  Keep in mind that `np.cov` is basically doing `data.dot(data.T)`.    What are you wanting to do? There are often mathematical shortcuts or alternatives to calculating the covariance matrix.

Comment: @JoeKington n is 256.  I want to calculate the sample covariance matrix.

Comment: Are you sure those dimensions aren't transposed, and that you aren't passing `rowvar=0`? A 256 x 256 float64 covariance matrix would only need ~500kB, whereas 94208 x 94208 would be ~71GB!

Comment: @ali_m I did do that at first.  Then I realized it and go the dimensions correct.  However, I closed Python(x,y), reopened it, ran my code w/ the correct dimensions, and it worked! Apparently getting the dimensions incorrect caused some buffers to fill such that when I ran the code w/ the correct dimensions directly after it fails.  Anyone know why/what buffer is filling or why I need to restart Python(x,y) to clear it?

Comment: Python garbage collection works in mysterious ways. When an array is deleted or goes out of scope, you can't expect the Python process to immediately release the corresponding chunk of memory back to the OS ([see here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm)). Having said that, I also find that I sometimes have to kill my Python process in order to release memory that it's been holding onto following an exception.